# How to show Matlab variable names with bash?

Tags: bash, matlab

I am using Matlab on a cluster since the data is quite big. Now I have .mat files where several variables are stored. Basically, I need to know the names of the variables stored in the .mat file (and downloading them to my computer to figure that out would take weeks..).
So, how do I do that?
Thanks

Comment: Please explain the problem better. Why can't you just load the `.mat` files in Matlab?

Comment: Your question contradicts your title: Do you want the *values* or the *names* of the variables?

Comment: contradiction edited..why not over matlab: it is faster this way, over matlab I have to start a job which stays in a queue for a requested node for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends on the format. There are various formats used by matlab.

See: http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf

But it could be also plain text and hdf.

Anyway reading the head is no problem, and easiest if done within matlab see: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.matfile.whos.html